# Wordpress Media Uploader Frame Multiple Item Selection Clear/Edit Tool

Tags: wordpress, frame, media, uploader

As part of a WP plugin I am creating, I am using Wordpress' Javascript/AJAX modal Uploader/gallery browser for multiple item selection. I am using this JS code;

```
  file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    multiple: true,
    library: {
      type: 'image'
    },
  });
```

This creates the frame as expected, but removes the left hand side bar, and the bottom edit/clear selection tool. Does anyone know how I can get these 2 things back?